# How to develop energy, rapture, tranquility and immersion?

Tags: enlightenment, energy

I am looking forward to develop 7 factors of enlightenment. The 7 factors of enlightenment are factors of mindfulness, investigation of principles, energy (viriya), rapture (piti), tranquility (passaddi), immersion (samadhi), and equanimity.
I have understood how to develop factors of mindfulness, investigation of principles and equanimity.

However I am not sure how to develop the following:

1. Energy (viriya)
2. Rapture (piti)
3. Tranquility(passaddi)
4. Immersion (samadhi)

(I guess Tranquility can be developed by becoming independent. If the answer to samadhi is to enter the first Jhana then my question will be how to enter it?)

So my question is: How to develop energy, rapture, tranquility and immersion? If you know answer to only one or few of the above factors then please post that as an answer. I will combine them.

Comment: Are you especially (or only) interested in sutta references?

Comment: I am interested in suttas primarily. Something like MN 117 which explains the path.

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole samyutta dedicated to the description and analysis of the Bojjhanga in the Connected Discourses (see [Bojjhanga Samyutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn46)). Also check out Ven. Piyadassi's great ["Seven Factors of Enlightenment"](https://accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/piyadassi/wheel001.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is such a good question! 
Each of these steps includes a further development of 'clarity', hence the first two steps - of mindfulness and investigation - to get this going.  An inspiring source, for some people, is in the essays of Ajahn Jeff, of Wat Metta.  These can be found in accesstoinsight.org.  His approach is so practical and sensible.

The sexual renunciation required for developing Steady Energy is just the gross aspect.  Steady Energy comes naturally out of constant practice when the mind becomes sufficiently calm.  Trying to develop this will only act against it.  This principle applies to all the remaining stages.

Comment: Thanks but I want to know whether Buddha showed how to develop Energy for example. I have found how to develop Rapture in language of Buddha. By developing strong faith in Buddha , Dhamma and Sangha one can develop Rapture. Viriya(energy) is a Sanskrit word  , it means sperm. Developing energy would mean conserving sperm and avoiding sex I guess.

Comment: Is *Ajahn Jeff* also known as [Thanissaro Bhikkhu (Geoffrey DeGraff)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/)? Are there any specific essays that you recommend, which address the OP's question?

Comment: Ajahn Jeff is indeed aka Thanissaro Bhikkhu, The best essay imho is "Wings to Awakening" but every thing else he does will develop the vital clarity needed to develop Right Understanding, from which the entire path develops.  One exception would be his essay on the Romantics, it didn't help me very much, though is interesting as a survey on Wrong View in western thought.

Answer (score 0):

I meditated for over a decade and found energy, rapture, tranquility, and immersion elusive in the comforts of modern daily life. Dhukka ruled instead.

And then I encountered fear and terror. That gave immediate energy and required tranquility as a base from which rapture and immersion could apply to burn fear and terror thoroughly away. Traditionally, monks choose seclusion in forests with tigers, graveyards, etc. It is difficult to find situations in modern life that engender constant yet manageable fear and terror. The forests are dying and we live in Disneyland. And yet these opportunities still do exist. For example meditating on breath while rock climbing is effective. You do have to be immersed or you will bumble and kill yourself or your partner. There is energy from the real challenge. Death and injury cannot be ignored. And rapture and tranquility do also emerge from this. Breathing in. Breathing out. Excellent practice. Sometimes there are professions suited for this--consider if you are a surgeon or tuk-tuk driver, someone's life is in your hands, fear and terror easily found.

If you have the opportunity to do so, live the [Bhaya-bherava Sutta: Fear & Terror](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.004.than.html). Breathe in. Breath out. Endure.